Autogenerate Player Number
I want to create a SSMS stored procedure to auto Generate player number like 000001,000002,000009,000010 and so on . I want it such that when I click on refresh on front end it should auto generate
ALTER proc [SDS].[usp_autgennum]
AS
BEGIN
    declare @playernumber varchar(50)

    select '00000'+ cast(max(cast(substring('000001',6,100) as int)) + 1 as varchar)  as playernumber
    from SDS.tblPlayerList
END


and what is your issue?

Save yourself some trouble and use sequences. The 0000 should be a formatting thing

Do not attempt to create an auto-incrementing number yourself.
This is error-prone and nearly impossible to do correctly in T-SQL.
Instead, rely on the already built-in features of SQL Server that can help you accomplish your goal - either use an identity column or a sequence object.
The leading zeros is a formatting issue and should be handled in display, not in the database.
However please note that when using identity or a sequence there might be gaps in the numbers generated for multiple reasons.
This isn't a bug, it's a feature that enables these auto-incrementing numbers to work as they should.
If you need your numbers to be continuous without gaps, you can use a computed column that's based on an identity or sequence to get that, however please note that it might carry a performance penalty, if done on the table itself.
If you're already using a stored procedure, the easiest and probably best way to do it would be to add a row_number() column and order it by id (assuming id is an identity column) - so the stored procedure would be something like this:
ALTER proc [SDS].[usp_autgennum]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS playernumber
      -- , whatever other columns you need here
    FROM SDS.tblPlayerList
END

and if you really must format the results with leading zeros, you do it like this:
SELECT RIGHT('000000' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) As varchar(6)), 6) AS playernumber
  -- , whatever other columns you need here
FROM SDS.tblPlayerList

